# Raspberry Pi- using LIRC for reverse engineering drone controller Infrared Signal

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, infrared, lirc

So I have a Raspberry Pi which has a Iguanaworks Infrared Transceiver connected to it. I am trying to use this in first phase to be able to reverse engineer what signals my drone controller sends so that I can use Leap Motion to control the drone. Is there someone out there who can confirm a drone controller + drone that are 100% reverse engineering-able using Iguanaworks Transceiver + the LIRC library? I even used `irrecord` so that I create my own `conf` file for the drone but I had not had any results.

Comment: Did you try to simply contact the vendor and ask for the IR protocol?

Comment: my drone is a UFO Mini Flying Ball with Gyro with two channels. I really don't think that they have a website/ a contact mail or something...and if they do, I really don't know where to get that from. At least google's first page is not helpful when searching this.

Comment: analysir https://www.analysir.com/blog/makes a great product that does exactly this and runs on the Pi. Besides the softweare they also sell the IR detectors and emitters as well. Sorry this is not a free solution, but the software works great.

Comment: thank you but apparently my setup is OK, it just confuses me that I tested just another now helicopter controller. Still acting the same! One of the sticks sends IR, it is seen by the transceiver, the trim buttons + the other stick are not seen as sending any IR. this is very strange